# From PHP variable to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I need to know how i get my PHP variable into JavaScript as a text. I will show you my code:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#krasvak').wScratchPad({
          scratchMove: function (e, percent) {
            console.log(percent);
            if (percent > 70)
            {
                this.clear();
                window.alert("U heeft uw code gekrast");
                window.location.href='compleet.php';        <!-- locatie waar je heen gaat na het krassen-->
            }
          }
        });
        $('#krasvak').wScratchPad('bg', 'HERE MUST THE VARIABLE COME ');        <!-- de onderste laag die vrijkomt-->
        $('#krasvak').wScratchPad('fg', 'images/overlay.png');      <!-- de laag die je weg krast-->
        $('#krasvak').wScratchPad('size', 15);
        $('#krasvak').wScratchPad('cursor', 'url("./images/coin.png") 5 5, default'); <!-- de muis in het krasgebied -->

      </script>
  <?php 

  $_COOKIE["number"];

  if ($_COOKIE["number"] < 5000)
  {
    $achtergrond = 'images/slide1.png';
  }
  else
  {
    $achtergrond = 'images/logo.jpg';
  }

  ?>
```

It is about the bg that is not empty.

Comment: show where you want to get php variable

Comment: Don't those HTML comments result in JavaScript syntax errors? Use JavaScript commenting instead here.

Comment: $('#krasvak').wScratchpad('BG', 'variable');

Comment: Hi OP. I've removed the 'cookies' tag, since as far as I can see the question is not actually about cookies. Similarly, we have a long-standing convention here that 'thanks in advance' and 'please help' are a bit too chatty, and are generally removed. Bear in mind that questions here are for posterity rather than just for each individual poster.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply echo your PHP variable into your JavaScript:

```
$('#krasvak').wScratchPad('bg', '<?php echo $achtergrond; ?>');
```

Of course, this requires your PHP run *before* your JavaScript: otherwise the PHP variable won't be set when this runs!

Comment: I tried but if i use this the scratch area dissapears

Comment: Rather than using quotes, you can do `$('#krasvak').wScratchPad('bg', <?php echo json_encode($achtergrond) ?>);` - that will correctly escape any quotes within, too.

Answer (score 0):

**It is not a good practice to call PHP code in JS**. It is hard to read an not a clean piece of code. But I know your problem. What you should do if you really need PHP in JS code is something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // define your php to js variables:
    var php_background = "<?php echo json_encode($achtergrond); ?>";
    // more variables to go here...

    $('#krasvak').wScratchPad('bg', php_background);

</script>
```

With this you get an fast overview of all your variables you get from PHP to use them in JS.

Comment: You're missing quotes around the PHP tags.

Comment: I'm not convinced as to why it's not good practice. How is it any different than calling PHP code in HTML? Or, more pertinently, how would you even get around it? In this case you could check the cookie with JS, certainly, but there are plenty of cases where you need to access PHP data from within non-PHP code.

Comment: There is one BIG difference: HTML is a markup language and JS is a programming language. You should avoid mixing programming Languages in your Code because it is hard to maintain and to read.

Answer (score 0):

Put your PHP code above the javascript. And use ur variable into javascript.

```
$('#krasvak').wScratchPad('bg', '<?php echo $achtergrond; ?>');
```

Comment: it didn't do the magic.